# How to get an image to resize in a widget layout to make room for other views in its container?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-widget

I'm struggling with a widget layout.  Essentially I have an image above some text, wrapped in a vertical LinearLayout container.  The image seems to take up all the space in the container (aligned at the bottom of the widget) forcing the text off the bottom of the widget and therefore its not visible.  Is there a way to get the image to auto-resize to avoid any other views below it from being forced out of the containers view?  Here's the code:

```
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/vertical_container"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">
        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/the_image"
            android:src="@drawable/image_32"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/the_poor_text_which_doesnt_show"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="Where am I?"
            android:textColor="#ffffff"
            android:textSize="11dip" />
    </LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using a RelativeLayout instead of a LinearLayout, declaring the TextView first with the parameter android:layout_alignParentBottom="true", and then the ImageView, with android:layout_above="@+id/the_poor_text_which_doesnt_show".

Comment: Ah, clever, I see what you've done there! This should force Android to process the height of the text first and allocate leftover space to the image (rather than the reverse as I currently have it). Thanks, I'll give that a try.